# What is this Bionicle-looking set?

Tags: set-identification, technic, bionicle

Can anyone identify this set?

[image: bionicle-looking toy]

Apparently my father has a bunch of these, and he's trying to figure out what to list on ebay. It appears to be at least Lego / Technic compatible, but I don't know much about Bionicle sets, so I don't know if it's name-brand or a knockoff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, those big Bionicle pieces all seem to have the word Lego and a mold number on them (albeit fairly tiny). To me, that weapon in the right hand (our left) looks like 55827c01 [Inika Light-up Laser Axe](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=55827c01&in=S), but that was in two sets, and neither is all-white like you have. So it appears to be a mix.

Comment: The white shoulders seem to be 53545 <https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=53545&colorID=1&in=A> so perhaps start from there?

Comment: Thank you, those links are very helpful!